# How to set anaconda as a default python?

Tags: 14.04, python3, paths, anaconda

I have just installed the Anaconda (for ipython notebook -- wanted to run some pandas programme). It is installed successfully but the problem here is whenever I type `which python`, it is always using a default python as `/usr/bin/python`

It will be great if someone can tell me how to setup the anaconda python as a default python. I am noob here till now I have just installed the anaconda in the default path as following `~/anaconda3`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

I have the same setup as you desire. In my case the `anaconda installer` added an entry in my `~/.bashrc` file. I don't know why yours did not. So to get to do what you want, add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="/home/yash/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

You need to refresh your env variables after this by opening a new terminal or using `source ~/.bashrc`

With this:

```
$ which python
/home/yash/anaconda3/bin/python
```

And `python -v` returns: `anaconda`

To get back to the former default, I comment out the entry setting the pathbin the `.bashrc` file and get these results:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python -v
python 2.7.*
```

Comment: That's fine, ofc. But I'd suggest using environments, that way you can create as many python envs as you want and switch between them using `source activate/deactivate`: https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

Comment: I have the above added to ~/.bashrc however which python does not return the anaconda3 version..... do I need to reboot for it to take effect?  Just installed anaconda.

Comment: # added by Anaconda3 installer
export PATH="/home/d/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Ah, I got it.  You need to refresh the environment variables either by re-opening a new terminal or typing source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding the entry in ~/.bashrc add the entry in ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile as it is a path and not an alias. Also, adding the path in bashrc may slower the terminal unnecessarily. To know the detailed meaning of ~/.bashrc and it's difference with the profile visit this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work.).

Answer (score 1):

After you installed Anaconda, just run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If you open the `.bashrc` file you can see it added Anaconda python to environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Setting anaconda3 python as default can be tricky espesially if you have several shells like zsh and bash. This means you have to include PATH variable in the default .rc file. An easy fix is just to add

`export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

to your `~/.profile` file. Then source the file by running `source ~/.profile` in a terminal.

Verify that it works by running `which python`. you should see `/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR 2019+**

In a new versions of Anaconda it is not recommended to add conda/bin to path manually. While installation ask you about run `conda init` press `yes` - conda will do all necessary option by itself.